Make 22.04 look like 24.04
I was clean installing Ubuntu 24.04 and ran into a bunch of problems (like my favorite Gnome extension CPU power manager not working, or GNOME crashing when changing themes), so I went back to 22.04 because I got work to do and just wanted to clean install.
However, I did like the overall feel of 24.04. The installer was mega, and the desktop environment felt phenomenal. I think they hit the ball out of the park with the UI design on that one. I really really liked the look of the panel system menu (with the controls for power, bluetooth, volume, etc.). I spent the majority of time after installing 22.04 trying to find if it's possible to bring that look to it.
I've so far come up empty handed. Aside from coding it myself, is there an obvious way I'm missing to make that happen? I've checked extensions.gnome.org and gnome-look.org and found some nice looking wallpapers along the way but not close to what I'm in search for. At least a definitive answer if it's a feature of the theme or built into the gnome release itself... And with the aforementioned websites and half others I checked having filtering and categorization options from hell, I'm giving up as its futile, at least until 24.04 is fixed which is when I will upgrade and have my sweet looking system menu again.
System menu in Ubuntu 24.04:


It won’t be very long before the first point release of a much more stable / tested version of 24.04 -  personally I’d wait for that. Given that the developers have spent 2 years moving from 22.04 to 24.04, I suspect it would take a very long time to emulate it in 22.04.

"Look and feel" is more than an extension or group of settings. It's four releases, library changes, two years of component redesigns and re-implementations, etc. Some features may be possible through an extension or two, but there is no easy way to make 22.04 behave completely like 24.04.
